# How to create channel on_ready discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to create come channels when bot starts. I want them to create in function on_ready. But `await guild.create_text_channel("Channel")` requires guild by itself. Usually when I want to create it by command I make something like this:

````
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(name="test channel")```

But I need ctx to create guild. So the question is: How do I create a channel without ctx?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to get a `discord.Guild` instance, you can get that using `Bot.get_guild`

```py
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    guild = client.get_guild(id_here)
    await guild.create_text_channel(name="whatever")
```

If you want to create a channel in all the guilds the bot is in you can loop through `client.guilds`

```py
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    for guild in client.guilds:
        await guild.create_text_channel(name="whatever")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20guild#discord.Client.get_guild)
- [`Bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem with disnake, and it took me reading through the api and testing things to figure it out. Since disnake is supposed to be forked off of `discord.py` try this

```py
@commands.command(name="obvious", description="given")
async def command(ctx: Context):
    await ctx.message.guild.create_text_channel("channel_name")
```

This solved my issue, and now I just need to add the parameters to properly sort channel creation.